# getLifecycle() returned null in ComponentActivity's constructor. Please make sure you are lazily constructing your Lifecycle

Tags: android, kotlin, appcompatactivity, lifecycleowner

i get this Error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getLifecycle() returned null in ComponentActivity's constructor. Please make sure you are lazily constructing your Lifecycle"

after change

From Place Play Service
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0"

to

New Places SDK Client
implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0"

Comment: Can you provide piece of problem code?